# How to have the data in the CSV file converted to JSON in the request body when using JMETER CSV Date set config

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

I have a CSV dataset config pointing to a CSV file with the following data:

```
Ids
87541
4551
15441
11117
.....
n
```

Instead of looping through the file and do multiple `POST` requests for each value, I need to have a single `POST` request and pass ALL the IDs  the request body which should like this in the generated `JSON`:

```
{
  "ids": [
    84280,
    2334,
    235,
    32554,
    3663,
    346,
    344643,
    ....,
    n
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which needs to send this JSON.
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def csvfile = new File('test.csv')
   def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

   jsonBuilder {
       ids csvfile.collect { it }
   }

   vars.put('requestBody', jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
   log.info(vars.get('requestBody'))
   ```

   The above code will read `test.csv` file in JMeter's "bin" folder and create an `ids` [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) where each element will be a line from the given file and put the result into `${requestBody}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Create JSON]

References:

- [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

In CSV Data Set Config define delimiter which not in file as `~`

Put in variable name `ids` for example.

and then use it in request as `{ "ids": [ ${ids} ] }`